# Create a Project in Komodo Edit

Tags: php, komodoedit

I have a set of PHP, HTML, CSS files that make up a website. I have got these files from a friend.

Is there a way to create a project from these existing files in Komodo Edit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're using Komodo Edit 6, and you've put all your files in a single directory, here is a step-by-step guide:

1. Create a new project: **Projects** -> **New Project...**
2. Enter a name, e.g. `website.komodoproject` and save it in your desired location
3. Open **Project** -> **Properties**
4. Open category **Directories and File Filters**
5. In *Specify the folder associated with this project*, enter the location where your website files reside. (you can also use the "Browse" button for that)
6. Press **OK** to accept the changes.
7. You're done. For more information, please read the [documentation about Projects](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.0/project.html).

Comment: If you save the project file in your files' top folder, you only need steps 1 and 2.